# How to increase memory limit in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

If I type

```
memory.limit()
```

in the console of Rstudio, I get "1e+13". Then, if I try to increase this memory limit by doing

```
memory.limit(1e+20)
```

or

```
memory.limit(size=1e+20)
```

I get an error: "Warning message: In memory.limit(size = 1e+20) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored". Which makes no sense. How can I increase this memory limit? (I am running on Windows 10 with 24GB of RAM).

Comment: Are your R and Rstudio 64bit? 32bit have a limit of max 4GB

Comment: I am using R 3.6.1 64 bit with no doubt. @keiv.fly